# Jacobi Gauss lobatto quadrature nodes and weights

Tags: numerical-methods

According to my calculations, For $N = 5$ i.e., $n=(0,1,2,3,4)$ and $\alpha = \beta = 0$ in the interval [-1, 1] the Jacobi Gauss Lobattto nodes are:
x = [-1, -0.655, 0, 0.655, 1] and its corresponding weights are:
w = [0.1, 0.544, 0.711, 0.544, 0.1].

Kindly assist me - are my calculations are correct or wrong?

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1329114617).

Comment: @Mattos Interesting site.

Comment: but if i 've alpha = beta = 1/2 then how can we find jacobi gauss lobatto nodes and weights?. this website is not showing results of lobatto for various choices of alpha and beta